# facebook landing page iframe wont resize

Tags: facebook, iframe, resize

Hi I have designed a custom facebook landing page and it is quite long but the iframe seems to be limited to a set length. getting the scrollbars turned on or off is not a problem, I can do this but regardless of having the scrollbars or not the iframe stays the same size. any ideas?

you can view the page here:
http://www.facebook.com/petsmarket?sk=app_199629183389823

cheers.

paul

Answer (score 1):

Change your IFrame size to **auto-resize** then use: [`FB.Canvas.setSize`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/)

P.S: Be-aware that your JS code is broken since you have it all in one line with comments in it!

Answer (score 0):

When you know desirable height the simplest way to do this is below (let it be 1200px):

```
<body onLoad="FB.Canvas.setSize({height: 1200})">
    ...
</body>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```